# Need help with pseudocode assignment! about reading record and add them and print them

Tags: pseudocode

A file of student records contains name, gender (M or F), age (in year) and marital status (single or married) for each student. Design an algorithm that will read through the file and calculate the number of married men, single men, and married women. Print these numbers on a student summary report. If any single men are over 30 year of age. Print their names and ages on a separate eligible bachelors report.

Can anyone tell me if I am wrong in any line? thanks! hope you can help me!

```
Set marriedMen to 0
Set singleMen to 0
Set marriedWomen to 0
Set singleWomen to 0 
READ name, sex, age, status
DOWHILE(NOT EOF)
IF (status = married) THEN  //check if status is married, if yes then check next
IF (sex = ‘F’) THEN     //check if sex is F, if yes then +1
marriedWomen = marriedWomen + 1
ELSE
IF (sex = ‘M’) THEN     //under married, and sex is M then +1
marriedMen = marriedMen + 1
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
IF (status = single) THEN   //check if status is single, if yes then check next
IF (sex = ‘F’) THEN     //check if sex is F, if yes then +1 to singleWomen
singleWomen = singleWomen + 1
ELSE
IF (sex = ‘M’) THEN     //under single, and sex is M then +1
singleMen = singleMen + 1
IF (age > 30) THEN      //under single, sex = M and age is over 30 then print the name, age
Print ‘Eligible bachelors Report’ 
Print ‘Name: ‘, name
Print ‘Age: ‘, age
ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF 
ENDIF
READ next record
ENDDO
Print ‘Student Summary Report’
Print ‘Married Men: ‘, marriedMen
Print ‘Single Men: ‘, singleMen
Print ‘Married Women: ‘, marriedWomen
Print ‘Single Women: ‘, singleWomen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below, I have done the following:

1. Added a `boolean` to prevent you from printing your `Eligible bachelors Report` header for every single line.
2. Indented your code so it is easier to read.
3. Replaced your use of `‘` with `'` because you obviously used a word processor such as MS-Word to write your code. (May I suggest [**NotePad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)?)

I left your code mostly intact: I take it for granted that `ElseIf` isn't a valid keyword in your pseudo code and that your professor might pass you a file with genders other than `M` and `F`.

```
Set marriedMen to 0
Set singleMen to 0
Set marriedWomen to 0
Set singleWomen to 0 
Set hasPrintedHeader to False

READ name, sex, age, status
DOWHILE(NOT EOF)
    IF (status = married) THEN  //check if status is married, if yes then check next
        IF (sex = 'F') THEN     //check if sex is F, if yes then +1
            marriedWomen = marriedWomen + 1
        ELSE
            IF (sex = 'M') THEN     //under married, and sex is M then +1
                marriedMen = marriedMen + 1
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    ENDIF

    IF (status = single) THEN   //check if status is single, if yes then check next
        IF (sex = 'F') THEN     //check if sex is F, if yes then +1 to singleWomen
            singleWomen = singleWomen + 1
        ELSE
            IF (sex = 'M') THEN     //under single, and sex is M then +1
                singleMen = singleMen + 1
                IF (age > 30) THEN      //under single, sex = M and age is over 30 then print the name, age
                    IF (hasPrintedHeader = False) THEN
                        Print 'Eligible bachelors Report'
                        hasPrintedHeader = True
                    END IF
                    Print 'Name: ', name
                    Print 'Age: ', age
                ENDIF
            ENDIF
        ENDIF 
    ENDIF
    READ next record
ENDDO

Print 'Student Summary Report'
Print 'Married Men: ', marriedMen
Print 'Single Men: ', singleMen
Print 'Married Women: ', marriedWomen
Print 'Single Women: ', singleWomen
```

Comment: hey thanks, meaning it will not print bachelors report after one time? but am i writing it correctly?

Comment: Yes, it will only print the words `Eligible bachelors Report` one time. And it looks like you are writing it correctly.

Comment: hey thanks justin, . but i was told to print on separate bachelors report and students report. meaning i have to break them? adding a break before displaying Eligible bachelors Report. will that do the job?

Answer (score -1):

DrawTree(n, direction, length)

```
if n > 0 do

    DrawTrunk(direction, length)

    DrawTree(n-1, 3DRandomAngle(direction), length*Factor(n))

    DrawTree(n-1, direction + random % 10, length*Factor(n))

    DrawTree(n-1, 3DRandomAngle(direction), length*Factor(n))

else

    DrawLeaf()

end if
```

end DrawTree